# Absolute position text inside table not aligning properly

Tags: html

I have a HTML code. There is a table with three rows and three columns. Each cell has some text. Everything is absolutely positioned. When I see this HTML in different browsers, all the browsers show it correctly except IE. Below is the part of HTML code which has problems. If you notice, IE is shifting the text up with every subsequent row. Rest of the browsers don't have this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE document PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<document xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="Author" content="***"/>
<meta name="DocumentName" content="Page"/>
<meta name="Date" content="07/21/2012"/>
<notice name="Page">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.Page61989 {}
.f1 {font-family:Arial;font-size:10.00pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:114%;}
p.normal, table.normal, div.normal {text-align:left; text-indent:0; margin-top:0in; margin-right:0in; margin-bottom:0.0in; margin-left:0in; clear:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="Page61989" style="position:relative;height:1056px;width:816px;">
<table class="normal" style="width:578.00px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1.00px solid #FF9900;position:absolute;top:328.00px;left:120.00px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:0.00px;" >This table has regular old</span><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:16.00px;left:0.00px;" >square corners.</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:192.00px;" >Cell 2 Row 1</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:384.00px;" >Cell 3  Row 1</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:0.00px;" >Cell 1 Row 2</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:192.00px;" >Cell 2 Row 2</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:384.00px;" >Cell 2 Row 3  This table has a</span><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:375.00px;left:384.00px;" >square corner defined.</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:16.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:0.00px;" >Added another row</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:16.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:192.00px;" >added another row</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:16.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:384.00px;" >added another row</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br style="clear:left;"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</notice>
</document>
```

Just to let you know that its an automatically generated code, so I have no option but to use absolute positioning. Also, some of the parts may not be valid or looks surprising but, please ignore them. Any ideas ?

Comment: why .000px? your whole markup is incorrect..

Comment: Alien is right. Simply delete all those incorrect inline span stylings as show in the answer below. E.g. `<span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:384.00px;" >` change it to `<span class="f1">` and it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this if helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE document PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<document xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="Author" content="***"/>
<meta name="DocumentName" content="Page"/>
<meta name="Date" content="07/21/2012"/>
<notice name="Page">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.Page61989 {}
.f1 {font-family:Arial;font-size:10.00pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:114%;}
p.normal, table.normal, div.normal {text-align:left; text-indent:0; margin-top:0in; margin-right:0in; margin-bottom:0.0in; margin-left:0in; clear:left;}

.tc{
    border:1px solid #FF9900
    }

</style>
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="Page61989" style="position:relative;height:1056px;width:816px;">

<table cellspacing="0" class="normal" style="width:578px;position:absolute;top:328px;left:120px;">  <tr>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
    <td class="tc">One-One</td>
  </tr>
</table>




</table><br style="clear:left;"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</notice>
</document>
```

below is ie6 screenshot

[image]

See below revised code as per your request.

```
<!DOCTYPE document PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<document xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="Author" content="***"/>
<meta name="DocumentName" content="Page"/>
<meta name="Date" content="07/21/2012"/>
<notice name="Page">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.Page61989 {}
.f1 {font-family:Arial;font-size:10.00pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:114%;}
p.normal, table.normal, div.normal {text-align:left; text-indent:0; margin-top:0in; margin-right:0in; margin-bottom:0.0in; margin-left:0in; clear:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="Page61989" style="position:relative;height:1056px;width:816px;">
<table class="normal" style="width:578.00px;border-collapse:collapse;border:1.00px solid #FF9900;position:absolute;top:328.00px;left:120.00px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:0.00px;" >This table has regular old</span><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:16.00px;left:0.00px;" >square corners.</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:192.00px;width:192.000px; ">Cell 2 Row 1</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:0.00px;left:384.00px;width:192.000px;" >Cell 3  Row 1</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:0.00px;" >Cell 1 Row 2</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:192.00px;width:192.000px;" >Cell 2 Row 2</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:31.00px;left:384.00px;width:192.000px;" >Cell 2 Row 3  This table has a</span><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:46.00px;left:384.00px;width:192.000px;" >square corner defined.</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:0.00px;width:192.000px;" >Added another row</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:192.00px;width:192.000px;" >added another row</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="height:31.000px;width:192.000px;border-top:1.00px solid #FF9900;border-left:1.00px solid #FF9900;" >
            <p class="normal"><span class="f1" style=";position:absolute;top:62.00px;left:384.00px;width:192.000px;" >added another row</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br style="clear:left;"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</notice>
</document>
```

Comment: I have given some of my comments above on why I cannot do what you have suggested.

Comment: view your HTML file in IE 7 or later

Comment: I checked it in IE9 and its also showing it incorrectly. Unfortunately, most of our clients use IE. ;-)

Comment: I checked your HTML file in IE 7 and IE 9 also and they both are showing it fine.

Comment: Did you notice that the second and third row text comes over the border lines of the table ? I would be surprised if text is properly aligned inside the boxes.

Comment: Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Comment: check for ie6 screenshot. i will try to add ie7 and ie9 screenshots also in a day.

Comment: oh.. you are talking about your code and I am talking about mine. I cannot use your code due to reasons I stated above. Did you see my code in IE ?

Comment: yes i have seen output of your code and in it some text overlaps in 2nd and 3rd row in IE. i will update my answer in case i manage to do so so that it works for you.

Comment: I found the issue. IE applies some styles by default and which was shifting the cells up. I reset the styles and it was looking like other browsers. :-) Thanks for looking at it Rishi. :-)